# участок кода opencart 2.0

Tags: opencart

Подскажите где найти этот значок домика (обведено на экранном снимке ниже) и переименовать на «главная»? Я не смог найти его в коде страницы в явном виде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот домик(home) часть "хлебных крошек"(breadcrumbs). В опенкатре крошки генерируются в контоллерах основных страниц(home, categoty, manufacturer, product и т.д.), для каждой страницы отдельно.
По вашему принтскрину понятно, что это категория. Контроллер категории товаров находится (для default и большинства кастомных шаблонов) по адресу

> ваш-сайт\catalog\controller\product\category.php
>   Вэтом файле найдите следующий код:

```
$data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
    'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
    'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
);
```

Это и есть первый элемент крошек - домик.`'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),` - этот код передаёт элементу массива text название хлебной крошки. Оно в свою очередь тянется из файлов локализации, содержащих переводы сайта. В вашем случае это ru, по адресу:

> ваш-сайт\catalog\language\russian\russian.php

в котором вам необходимо найти следующую строчку - `$_['text_home'] = '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>';`
Собственно вот он - домик, элемент набора иконок font awesome.

**И, если интересно:**

Файл представления категории товаров находится тут:

> ваш-сайт\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.tpl

В этом файле ищите следующий код (обычно почти в самом начале):

```
<?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></span></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Это и есть цикл формирования элементов хлебных крошек. Первым элементом, который выстраивает цикл, является роут на home в нём переменная `$breadcrumb['text']` как-раз и передаёт тот самый домик.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!)